# Mocking errors with client-go fake client

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, kubernetes, client-go

I'm using client-go (the k8s client for go) to programmatically retrieve and update some secrets from my cluster. While doing this, I'm facing the need of unit-testing my code, and after some investigation I stumbled upon client-go's `fake` client. However, I haven't been able to mock errors yet. I've followed the instructions from [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/742#issuecomment-633676780), but without any success.

Here you have my business logic:

```golang
func (g goClientRefresher) RefreshNamespace(ctx context.Context, namespace string) (err error, warnings bool) {
    client := g.kubeClient.CoreV1().Secrets(namespace)
    secrets, err := client.List(ctx, metav1.ListOptions{LabelSelector: "mutated-by=confidant"})
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to fetch secrets from cluster: %w", err), false
    }

    for _, secret := range secrets.Items {
        // business logic here
    }
    return nil, warnings
}
```

And the test:

```golang
func TestWhenItsNotPossibleToFetchTheSecrets_ThenAnErrorIsReturned(t *testing.T) {
    kubeClient := getKubeClient()
    kubeClient.CoreV1().(*fakecorev1.FakeCoreV1).
        PrependReactor("list", "secret", func(action testingk8s.Action) (handled bool, ret runtime.Object, err error) {
            return true, &v1.SecretList{}, errors.New("error listing secrets")
        })
    r := getRefresher(kubeClient)


    err, warnings := r.RefreshNamespace(context.Background(), "target-ns")


    require.Error(t, err, "an error should have been raised")
}
```

However, when I run the test I'm getting a `nil` error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the error... it is in the resource name of the reactor function, I had `secret` and it should be the plural `secrets` instead... :facepalm:. So this is the correct version of the code:

```golang
func TestWhenItsNotPossibleToFetchTheSecrets_ThenAnErrorIsReturned(t *testing.T) {
    kubeClient := getKubeClient()
    kubeClient.CoreV1().(*fakecorev1.FakeCoreV1).
        PrependReactor("list", "secrets", func(action testingk8s.Action) (handled bool, ret runtime.Object, err error) {
            return true, &v1.SecretList{}, errors.New("error listing secrets")
        })
    // ...
}
```